# The if statement is not registering variables changing

Tags: python, pygame

The if statement is not realising that car1num and car2num changing and just ignoring them breaking the car switching and turning of the car.

ok in the code just below game_loop() it says "**car2num = 2**" and "**car1num = 1**" then later on it says

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if crashed == 0:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RCTRL:
                    car2num += 1
                    if car2num == 4:
                        car2num = 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL:
                    car1num += 1
                    if car1num == 4:
                        car1num = 1
```

so every time you press RCRTL car2num goes up and every time you press LCRTL car1num goes up and even later( there is one for both **car1num** and **car2num** )

```
        if car2num == 1:
            car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1.png')
        if car2num == 2:
            car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2.png')
        if car2num == 3:
            car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3.png')
```

So then the number of car1/2num decides the car.

but it will always stay as the car it was originally set as "**car2num = 2**" and "**car1num = 1**".

Thank you for helping in advance and sorry for being disorganised.

## Full Code

```
import pygame
import os
from random import randint
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import random
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.init()
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
diswidth = 800
dishight = 600
cap = int(randint(0,4))

if cap == 1:
    caption = 'Light Drive - beat your friends'
elif cap == 2:
    caption = "Light Drive - don't crash"
elif cap == 3:
    caption = 'Light Drive - drive car drive!!!'
elif cap == 4:
    caption = 'Light Drive - BRUM BRUM'
else:
    caption = 'Light Drive - error'

car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1.png')
car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2.png')
car3IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3.png')
car4IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car4.png')
car5IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car5.png')
car0IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car0.png')
onewinIMG = pygame.image.load('textures\Player-One.png')
twowinIMG = pygame.image.load('textures\Player-Two.png')
track = pygame.image.load('textures\TRACK.png')
def car1 (x1,y1):
    gameDisplay.blit(car1IMG,(x1,y1))
def car2 (x2,y2):
    gameDisplay.blit(car2IMG,(x2,y2))
def onewin ():
    gameDisplay.blit(onewinIMG,(((diswidth/2)-251),((dishight/2)-102.5)))
def twowin ():
    gameDisplay.blit(twowinIMG,(((diswidth/2)-267),((dishight/2)-102.5)))



def car3 (x3,y3):
    gameDisplay.blit(car3IMG,(x3,y3))

def car4 (xx4,yy4):
    gameDisplay.blit(car4IMG,(x4,y4))

def car5 (xx5,yy5):
    gameDisplay.blit(car5IMG,(x5,y5))



black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)
orange = (255,112,0)
purple = (255,0,255)
cyan = (0,255,255)
grey = (112,112,112)

pygame.display.set_caption(caption)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def text(texts, color):
    font = pygame.font.Font('fonts\HWAndy.ttf',72)
    wintext = font.render(texts, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(wintext, (((diswidth/2)-200), (dishight/2)))
    gameDisplay.blit(wintext,)


def game_loop():
    rotation2 = 1
    rotation1 = 1
    car2num = 2
    car1num = 1
    fullscreen = False
    x1 = ((diswidth * 0.5)-32)
    x2 = ((diswidth * 0.5)-32)
    y1 = ((76))
    y2 = ((44))
    x2c = 0
    x1c = 0
    y2c = 0
    y1c = 0
    car0 = 0
    car3 = 0
    car4 = 0
    car5 = 0
    y3 = (dishight + 300)
    y4 = (dishight + 300)
    y5 = (dishight + 300)
    y0 = (dishight + 300)
    car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1.png')
    car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2.png')
    crashed = 0
    gameExit = False
    winner = 0
    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if crashed == 0:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RCTRL:
                        **car2num += 1**
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL:
                        **car1num += 1**
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        x2c = (0-(diswidth * 0.005))
                        rotation2 = 3
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        x2c = (diswidth * 0.005)
                        rotation2 = 1
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        y2c = (0-(dishight * 0.005))
                        rotation2 = 0
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        y2c = (dishight * 0.005)
                        rotation2 = 2
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        x1c = (0-(diswidth * 0.005))
                        rotation1 = 3
                    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                        x1c = (diswidth * 0.005)
                        rotation1 = 1
                    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                        y1c = (0-(dishight * 0.005))
                        rotation1 = 0
                    if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        y1c = (dishight * 0.005)
                        rotation1 = 2
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        gameExit = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        x2c = 0
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        x2c = 0
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        y2c = 0
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        y2c = 0
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        x1c = 0
                    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                        x1c = 0
                    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                        y1c = 0
                    if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        y1c = 0
        car = random.randrange(0,100)
        if car == 0:
            car0 = 1
        if car == 1:
            car3 = 1
        if car == 2:
            car4 = 1
        if car == 3:
            car5 = 1

        if crashed == 0:
            x2 = x2 + x2c
            x1 = x1 + x1c
            y2 = y2 + y2c
            y1 = y1 + y1c
        gameDisplay.fill(grey)
        gameDisplay.blit(track,(0,0))

        if crashed < 60 and crashed > 0:
            crashed = (crashed + 1)
        **if rotation2 == 0:
            if car2num == 1:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1.png')
            if car2num == 2:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2.png')
            if car2num == 3:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3.png')
        if rotation2 == 1:
            if car2num == 1:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1 right.png')
            if car2num == 2:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2 right.png')
            if car2num == 3:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3 right.png')
        if rotation2 == 2:
            if car2num == 1:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1 back.png')
            if car2num == 2:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2 back.png')
            if car2num == 3:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3 back.png')
        if rotation2 == 3:
            if car2num == 1:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1 left.png')
            if car2num == 2:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2 left.png')
            if car2num == 3:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3 left.png')
        if rotation1 == 0:
            if car1num == 1:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1.png')
            if car1num == 2:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2.png')
            if car1num == 3:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3.png')
        if rotation1 == 1:
            if car1num == 1:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1 right.png')
            if car1num == 2:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2 right.png')
            if car1num == 3:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3 right.png')
        if rotation1 == 2:
            if car1num == 1:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1 back.png')
            if car1num == 2:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2 back.png')
            if car1num == 3:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3 back.png')
        if rotation1 == 3:
            if car1num == 1:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1 left.png')
            if car1num == 2:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2 left.png')
            if car1num == 3:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3 left.png')
        if x1 > (diswidth - 194):
            if car1num == 1:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1crashed.png')
            if car1num == 2:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2crashed.png')
            if car1num == 3:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3crashed.png')
            if crashed == 0:
                crashed = 1
                winner = 2
        if x1 < 130:
            if car1num == 1:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1crashed.png')
            if car1num == 2:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2crashed.png')
            if car1num == 3:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3crashed.png')
            if crashed == 0:
                crashed = 1
                winner = 2
        if y1 > (dishight - 94):
            if car1num == 1:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1crashed.png')
            if car1num == 2:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2crashed.png')
            if car1num == 3:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3crashed.png')
            if crashed == 0:
                crashed = 1
                winner = 2
        if y1 < 30:
            if car1num == 1:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1crashed.png')
            if car1num == 2:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2crashed.png')
            if car1num == 3:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3crashed.png')
            if crashed == 0:
                crashed = 1
                winner = 2
        if x2 > (diswidth - 194):
            if car2num == 1:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1crashed.png')
            if car2num == 2:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2crashed.png')
            if car2num == 3:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3crashed.png')
            if crashed == 0:
                crashed = 1
                winner = 1
        if x2 < 130:
            if car2num == 1:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1crashed.png')
            if car2num == 2:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2crashed.png')
            if car2num == 3:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3crashed.png')
            if crashed == 0:
                crashed = 1
                winner = 1
        if y2 > (dishight - 94):
            if car2num == 1:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1crashed.png')
            if car2num == 2:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2crashed.png')
            if car2num == 3:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3crashed.png')
            if crashed == 0:
                crashed = 1
                winner = 1
        if y2 < 30:
            if car2num == 1:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1crashed.png')
            if car2num == 2:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2crashed.png')
            if car2num == 3:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3crashed.png')
            if crashed == 0:
                crashed = 1
                winner = 1
        if x2 > 185 and x2 < 550 and y2 > 85 and y2 < 450:
            if car2num == 1:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1crashed.png')
            if car2num == 2:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2crashed.png')
            if car2num == 3:
                car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3crashed.png')
            if crashed == 0:
                crashed = 1
                winner = 1
        if x1 > 195 and x1 < 540 and y1 > 95 and y1 < 440:
            if car1num == 1:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1crashed.png')
            if car1num == 2:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2crashed.png')
            if car1num == 3:
                car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car3crashed.png')
            if crashed == 0:
                crashed = 1
                winner = 2**


        car1(x1,y1)
        car2(x2,y2)
        if crashed == 60:
            crashed = 0
            gameDisplay.fill(black)
            if winner == 1:
                onewin()
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(2)
            if winner == 2:
                twowin()
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(2)
            winner = 0
            x1 = ((diswidth * 0.5)-32)
            x2 = ((diswidth * 0.5)-32)
            y1 = ((76))
            y2 = ((44))
            x2c = 0
            x1c = 0
            y2c = 0
            y1c = 0
            rotation2 = 1
            rotation1 = 1
            car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1.png')
            car2IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car2.png')
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: I have *absolutely* no idea what you want or what your problem is. Neither your description nor the code (dump) explain what's wrong

Comment: You really need to provide a [MCVE] and clearly state the difference between the expected and the real behaviour. Otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: You got a couple of downvotes because your question currently is hard to understand. This is nothing personal, it's just an indicator that this particular question needs to be edited to follow the [ask] guidelines. You need to explain where in the code it is and what's suppose to happen. We want to help so don't be put down by the downvotes and comments. Oki? :)

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur Please don't write condescending and non-constructive comments. _"put more effort"_ don't describe what to do and the avatar might have been default if signed up with google+ or Facebook.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I apologize to the green penguin. I've deleted the comment.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur Thank you for apologising

Comment: @thegreenpenguin Is the code run inside the if-statement? If you put `print('ok')` after `if event.key == pygame.K_RCTRL:` does it print `'ok'`? I've had problems with left and right control on my mac not being identified so that could be a problem.

Comment: Yes it does print ok.

Comment: Thing I don't get with this is that it used to work then just stopped.

Comment: I think I know the issue. Does it work if you write `global car1IMG` and `global car2IMG` at the top of the `game_loop` function?

Comment: @Ted Klein Bergman that works thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have functions such as

```
def car1 (x1,y1):
    gameDisplay.blit(car1IMG,(x1,y1))
```

which will blit the global image `car1IMG`. Then in your `game_loop` function you write `car1IMG = pygame.image.load('textures\car1.png')` which creates a *local* variable with the same name. So everything in your `game_loop` function will always use the local variable instead of the global, unless you specify that `car1IMG` is a global variable. As such:

```
def game_loop():
    gloabl car1IMG
    ...
```